# HTML5 type=range - showing label

Tags: html

Is there a way I can also set some label text for each steps in the HTML5 type=range control. Basically I have a range control `<input type="range" step=1 min=0 max=4>` and for each steps I want some label to be shown in the control. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is browser-dependent, and it depends on how the browser implements it

Comment: Are there any specific tags to add labels for each steps? What are the browser it supports?

Comment: Some more info on the current state of the range type: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/8-range.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've put together for you.

```js
// define a lookup for what text should be displayed for each value in your range
var rangeValues =
{
    "1": "You've selected option 1!",
    "2": "...and now option 2!",
    "3": "...stackoverflow rocks for 3!",
    "4": "...and a custom label 4!"
};


$(function () {

    // on page load, set the text of the label based the value of the range
    $('#rangeText').text(rangeValues[$('#rangeInput').val()]);

    // setup an event handler to set the text when the range value is dragged (see event for input) or changed (see event for change)
    $('#rangeInput').on('input change', function () {
        $('#rangeText').text(rangeValues[$(this).val()]);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="1" min="1" max="4">
<label id="rangeText" />
```

Comment: In the example you have set one label text, but my question is more on I have display text for each steps for eg: Display name A for value 1, B->2 etc which would appear under each steps under the slider. The idea is that I want to use slider instead of a combo box and I want the display items coming in dropdown shown as text under each steps

Comment: How can I put those labels below the input to their corresponding values?

Answer (score 23):

I guess the easiest solution (plain Javascript) is:

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="rangeVal">resolution (dpi):</label>
    <input type ="range" max="1000" min="20"
        oninput="document.getElementById('rangeValLabel').innerHTML = this.value;"
        step="1" name="rangeVal" id="rangeVal" value="200">
    </input>
    <em id="rangeValLabel" style="font-style: normal;"></em>
</fieldset>
```

This code does not need jQuery nor CSS and should work on any browser that supports the range input type.

Answer (score 20):

Here's an alternative solution, no jQuery required.  Uses the HTML5 `oninput` event handler, and `valueAsNumber` property of the input element.

**Works on my machine certification:** Chrome v54

```html
<form name="myform" oninput="range1value.value = range1.valueAsNumber">
  <input name="range1" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="4" value="1">  
  <output name="range1value" for="range1" >1</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

OP,

I put together a demo that uses a `range` input with corresponding `<p>` tags that act as both labels for the current state of the slider, as well as triggers to change the slider's value.

#### Plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/ArOkBVvUVUvtng1oktZG?p=preview.

---

#### HTML Markup

```
<div class="rangeWrapper">
    <input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="4" step="1" value="1"  /> 
    <p class="rangeLabel selected">Label A</p>
    <p class="rangeLabel">Label B</p>
    <p class="rangeLabel">Label C</p>
    <p class="rangeLabel">Label D</p>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[type='range']").change(function() {
    slider = $(this);
    value = (slider.val() -1);

    $('p.rangeLabel').removeClass('selected');
    $('p.rangeLabel:eq(' + value + ')').addClass('selected');

  });

  $('p.rangeLabel').bind('click', function(){
    label = $(this);
    value = label.index();
    $("input[type='range']").attr('value', value)
                            .trigger('change');
  });

});
```

#### CSS

```
input[type="range"] {
    width: 100%;
}

p.rangeLabel {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: rgb(136,136,136);
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height 20px;
}

p.rangeLabel:hover {
    background-color: rgb(3, 82, 3);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p.rangeLabel.selected {
    background-color: rgb(8, 173, 8);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Also worth nothing, if you're interested in showing the **current** value as a label/flag to the user, (instead of many) there's a great [article by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/) on value bubbles for range sliders.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way of doing it. And as input[type=range] is very poorly supported, I will recommend using jQuery UI slider and the way of attaching labels found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider) in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jSlider. Its a jQuery slider plugin for range inputs.

https://github.com/egorkhmelev/jslider

Just check out the demos and documentation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the standard ([HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#range-state-typerange), [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#range-state-(type%3Drange))),  specifies a `label` attribute for `option`s when using a `datalist`. Sample code [here](https://simpl.info/datalist).

This isn't implemented by any browser yet.