# Create draggable line using easy trick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this task, create `draggable` line like this `img` I want when I press plus button value increment and etc.
please tell me how to create this script very easy if you know any plug in like this please give me links
thank for help :)

[image]

Comment: like this? [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: yeas, Like this but I want add number increment and decrement buttons

Comment: You could have just Googled _jquery slider with values displayed_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution to the problem using jQuery UI (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rz12wbcL/)

```js
$(function() {
    var btnDec = $('.dec');
    var btnInc = $('.inc');
      
    var slider = $( "#slider" ).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 30,
        step: 5,
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(ui.value);
            $('#slider_value').val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    btnInc.click(function () { slider.slider('value', slider.slider('value') + 5 ); $('#slider_value').val(slider.slider('value')); });
    btnDec.click(function () { slider.slider('value', slider.slider('value') - 5 ); $('#slider_value').val(slider.slider('value')); });
});
```

```css
#slider_container * {
    float: left;
}
#slider {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
input {
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider_container">
    <button class="dec">-</button>
    <div id='slider' style='width: 100px;'></div>
    <input type="text" id="slider_value" value="0" />
    <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
```