# jQuery UI slider labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have the following UI slider on my page.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $( "#slider-payback" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value:100,
            min: 18,
            max: <?php echo json_encode($max_payback); ?>,
            step: 6,

            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#payback-period" ).val( "" + ui.value )
                totalPayableFunc();
                monthlyPaymentsFunc();
            }
        });
        $( "#payback-period" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-payback" ).slider( "value" ) );
        totalPayableFunc();
        monthlyPaymentsFunc();
    });
```

Is it possible to easily add a 'min' and 'max' label on the slider though? I'm yet to attempt this because I'm unsure of the best way to tackle it.

Thanks

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm attempting to add a 'min' label at the one end of the slider and a 'max' label at the other end. I'm just not sure what the best way is to tackle this.

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-pricing-slider-donations - this example shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about any external library but it is not possible with Jquery Slider itself.

But since you need only Min and Max header you could use following with combination HTML and CSS.

Add labels before and after Slider element in HTML.

```
<label>Min</label><div id="slider"></div><label>Max</label>
```

User below simple CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 50%;
    float :left;
}
label
{
    float : left;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/f74wzh8y/

You could also take a look at this. 
[jQuery UI Slider Labels Under Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider)

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-pricing-slider-donations